# Celery KeyError when i try to execute task

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

In accordance with the 'first steps with Celery'
I have the following structure:

Celery_

- config

  - celery.py
  - celeryconfig.py
- tasks

  - tasks.py
- run_tasks.py

celery.py:

```
from celery import Celery
from config import celeryconfig
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://')
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
```

celeryconfig.py

```
broker_url = 'pyamqp://'
result_backend = 'rpc://'
task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
timezone = 'Europe/Oslo'
enable_utc = True

task_routes = {
'tasks.add': 'low-priority',
}
task_annotations = {
   'tasks.add': {'rate_limit': '10/m'}
}
```

tasks.py:

```
from config.celery import app


@app.task
def add(x, y):
return x + y
```

run_tasks.py:

```
from tasks.tasks import add
res = add.delay(4,4)
a = res.get()
print(a)
```

This is a very simple configuration, but when I run run_tasks.py, the console displays an error:

> .... Traceback (most recent last call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 
>     456, in on_task_received
>       strategies [name] (message, body,
>     KeyError: 'tasks.tasks.add'

Help me please. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import your tasks in celery.py

```
from celery import Celery
from config import celeryconfig
app = Celery('tasks.tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://')
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
import tasks.tasks
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have one more problem. In the celeryconfig.py file, I declared a time limit for the add task: 'task_annotations = {
    'tasks.tasks.add': {'rate_limit': '10 / m '}
} '. But I can perform the task as many times as I want. What could be wrong?